# Tmux: How do I use this key binding?

Tags: tmux

I just downloaded dotfiles (https://github.com/skwp/dotfiles) and don't understand the tmux config:

```
# Create splits and vertical splits
bind-key v split-window -h -p 50 -c "#{pane_current_path}"
bind-key ^V split-window -h -p 50 -c "#{pane_current_path}"
bind-key s split-window -p 50 -c "#{pane_current_path}"
bind-key ^S split-window -p 50 -c "#{pane_current_path}"
```

Pressing `v` anywhere doesn't split the window when I am in a tmux session. What else am I supposed to press?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but if you press `^b` (CTLR + B) - to enter tmux "mode", then the `bind-key`. For example, `^b` followed by `v` should be the first option on the list. I'm not sure if `^V` is CTLR+V or CTLR+SHIFT+V.

Comment: none of those worked for me unfortunately

Comment: ohhhh i know why, they had this in the file `unbind C-b
set -g prefix C-a
` it worked!!! `CTRL + A` and then `v`

Comment: `^a` (or CTLR+A) was the mode key combo for _screen_, which is a similar but older program to tmux. I guess someone liked the old _screen_ key combo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my tmux.conf:

`bind | split-window -h`

`bind "-" split-window -v`

For splite, un push `CTRL+B` and after `CTRL+-` ou `CTRL+|`

So i think for you `CTRL+B` and `CTRL+v`